# How to structure Python module to make it both extensible and testible?

Tags: python, unit-testing, module, structure

I'm writing a couple Python modules to be used in my own application handling crypto-currencies. Many of the functions return something based upon a given string:

```
def doStuff(coin, value):
    if coin == 'BTC':
        return doSomethingWithBTC(value, 'some_string')
    elif coin == 'LTC':
        return someModule.doLTC(value, 1)
    elif coin == 'DOGE':
        return otherMod.DOGE(value, 52, True)
    else:
        return 'Some terrible error occurred.'
```

As you can see, the key is one of a predefined set of strings (crypto-currencies). At the moment there are three in the set, but I want to extend this number in the future. I've got a dozen more functions in this module, which at the moment all take the same three strings, but when I add one, all the functions need to be extended.

I've got unit tests for this module in which I now want to test whether all the functions are able to take all the (currently 3) items from the set as a key. I could do this by calling them, but some of them do stuff which I can't really test in unit tests. One of them makes (Bitcoin) payments for example.

I now thought of using the inspect module to get the source code of the functions and see if it contains a line containing `key == 'X'`, where X is each item from the pre-defined set. Although I guess this will work, it doesn't sound very Pythonic to me.

Does anybody know how I can make these functions such that I can test whether they are able to handle all currencies in the pre-defined set without actually calling the functions? All tips are welcome!

Comment: For one thing, it isn't very Pythonic to have a lot of `elif`s - consider a dictionary instead - you can at least then check that all keys are in that dictionary. Second, how do you ensure that it isn't a trivial `elif key == 'X': raise NotImplementedError` or `pass` or `print("Don't know how to do this.")`?

Comment: Where is `key` defined?

Comment: You should really consider making the `else` case `raise ValueError("Invalid coin: '{0}'.".format(coin))`

Answer (score 2):

Using if-cascades is not very pythonic either. If you have many methods for each key, just use classes and access them via a dictionary:

```
class BTC(object):
    def do_stuff(self, value):
        return doSomethingWithBTC(value, 'some_string')

class LTC(object):
    ...

CURRENCIE_INSTANCES = {
    'BTC': BTC(),
    'LTC': LTC(),
}

def do_stuff(key, value):
    return CURRENCIE_INSTANCES[key].do_stuff(value)
```

That way, you don't have to change your stuff-methods, but only one dictionary.

Comment: It totally does, because the OP doesn't have to change and test every function.

Comment: +1 I would also solve this through OOP polymorphism.  Adding a new currency then means adding a new class which overrides any methods where behavior needs to differ from the base class.  Perhaps add something more about how to decide which class to use as a base?

Comment: This does not address how to test things which cannot be tested, but that part of the question is poorly specified anyway.  A common trick is to create a `Mock` object which accepts the call and checks that the parameters are as expected, or whatever.  The things which cannot be done in tests obviously cannot be tested.

Comment: Implementing a base class which accepts transactions etc would make the base class easy to test, and then you only have to test the overridden behavior for the child classes (where testing is possible).  The base class could simply do transactions against a local back end with a database which records transactions and maintains an account balance.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
from functools import partial

def doStuff(key, value):

    method_btc = partial(doSomethingWithBTC, kw2='some_string')
    method_ltc = partial(someModule.doLTC, kw2=1)
    method_doge = pattial(otherMod.DOGE, kw2=52, kw3=True)
    dct = dict(BTC=method_btc, LTC=method_ltc, DOGE=method_doge)

    if key in dct:
        return dct.get(key)(value)
    else:
        return 'Some terrible error occurred.'
```

You can always expand dictionary ***dct*** with new key and method.